# Extracting values from NSDictionary to individual variables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I really thought this was Xcode playing up as I can't for the life of me see what is causing this error in a fairly simple piece of Swift code but after restarting cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, and restarting my MacBook I'm still getting the same error.... But why!!??!!

Here is the code

```
// Loop through records saving them
for recordItem in records {
    if let record: NSDictionary = recordItem as? NSDictionary {                
        let time: String = record["time"] as! String
        let record: String = record["record"] as! String
        let recordId: String = record["record_id"] as! String
        let saveTime: String = record["save_time"] as! String
        let setId: String = record["set_id"] as! String

        // Does more stuff
    }
}
```

records is an NSArray and it is made from data downloaded from a remote server.

All is fine until the line beginning let recordId. This and the two lines below it are giving an error - Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'

Why? And why is there no problem with the 2 lines above? And how do I fix it?

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm at a bit of a dead end.

Comment: "let record: String" and "let record: NSDictionary" should be different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the variable `record` to unwrap the optional `recordItem` but then you are re-assigning `record` as `record["record"]` - so from this point on it becomes a String, not a Dictionary - resulting in the error message *Cannot subscript a value of type 'String' with an index of type 'String'*

You just need to change one of the `record` variables

```
for recordItem in records {
    if let unwrappedRecord: NSDictionary = recordItem as? NSDictionary {
        let time: String = unwrappedRecord["time"] as! String
        let record: String = unwrappedRecord["record"] as! String
        let recordId: String = unwrappedRecord["record_id"] as! String
        let saveTime: String = unwrappedRecord["save_time"] as! String
        let setId: String = unwrappedRecord["set_id"] as! String

        // Does more stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: How stupid of me! I don't know how I didn't see it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here, you are declaring `record` as a `String`, previously it was `NSDictionary` and due to scope the `record` in `record["record_id"]` is `String` not `NSDictionary`. Quick fix is to change the name as I did

```
    let time: String = record["time"] as! String
    let record1: String = record["record"] as! String
    let recordId: String = record["record_id"] as! String
    let saveTime: String = record["save_time"] as! String
    let setId: String = record["set_id"] as! String
```

Comment: No, it was 4 minutes after mine